# EXCEL 2010 conditional formatting multiple colors and dates

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I am trying to set multiple cells to stay green when the date is within 120 days of the current date, yellow between 121 and 180 days old and red when date is 181 days and older. It would also need to change back and forth when new dates are entered.

Answer (score 1):

Select your cells (date),

> Use Conditional Formatting
>   New Rules
>   Use a formula to determine which cell to format
>   Format values where this Formula is True
>   write the following:
>   **=(Today()-A1)<=120**
>   Format Green
>   Repeat the above instructions and write the second formula:
>   **=And((Today()-A1)>=121,(Today()-A1)<=180)**
>   and Format Yellow
>   Repeat again the above instructions and write the third formula:
>   **=(Today()-A1)>=181**
>   and Format Red
>   A1 is the starting cell where is your date, Today() is the current Date in Excel
>   The cells will color automatically depending of the date written